# Is it safe to toggle bottom menu based on initial window.innerHeight value?

Tags: javascript

### The question

When `window.onresize` event is fired, the bottom menu should become hidden *if* `window.innerHeight` is *smaller* than it was at `window.onload`.

Will this behave consistently across mobile browsers and operational systems?

---

### Rationale

This is the solution I found to deal with the fact that mobile keyboards resize the viewport when they come out. If the bottom menu is not hidden when the keyboard comes into view, it will get stacked upon the keyboard.

This solution works as expected on Chrome v80 running on Android 7.1.
I wonder, however, if the below cases are common, since they would brake the mechanism:

- Browsers that won't trigger the resize event when the keyboard comes in and/or leaves
- Systems/browsers that keep the keyboard visible while navigating to a new page, therefore making the initial `window.innerHeight` value different from the actual viewport size without keyboard

---

**Important**: Doing the toggling through Input focus/blur events is out of question. I've found that on my Android phone, when the System's go-back button is pressed, the keyboard hides, but the input does not lose focus, therefore the bottom menu stays hidden.

Comment: What if you were asking a real question based on something concrete?

Comment: @MisterJojo The question is short and clear enough. It doesn't regard a specific implementation, it regards the browser API. I'd rather screenshot what you have said in order to make a case for downvote buttons on comments

Comment: Why ?, showing your code is prohibited?